# Django: Is there any way to delay the loading and rendering of included template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Say, I have the following template snippet:

```
  <div class="endless_page_template">
    {% include page_template %}
  </div>
```

The snippet is within a tab, which is behind other tabs when the page is first loaded and its content won't show until user clicks on the tab.

**Question:** Is there any way to delay the loading and rendering of `page_template` until a specific event is triggered at the client-side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change that template to have a little AJAX loader graphic as the contents. Then create a new view to load page_template from an AJAX request that is triggered on the tab's click event.

Comment: Ok. Then what's the AJAX response is going to look like? The rendered html of page_template?

Comment: Exactly. You create a view (or use request.is_ajax within the existing view) that returns just page_template. Then you use something like the .load() method in jQuery to replace the contents of the tab with the response from that view when the tab label's onclick event is fired.

Answer (score 2):

I have [django-partial-page](https://bitbucket.org/siberiano/django-partial-page) application with middleware that delays blocks rendering and also has Javascript that allows loading of those blocks. It's not intended exactly for tabbed forms, but with a little of code one can make it.

Run the example project on your machine and see how it handles `delayed_block` tag.

Comment: This sounds like what I am exactly looking for. Will take a look and let you know how it works out. Thanks

Comment: Ask me questions on email or elsewhere about the application, it might need an update.

Comment: I am still in the process of deciding which approach to take. Will accept your answer if I have decided to go with your app. Thanks.

Comment: After comparing your app to @Micah's approach, I find that Micah's is a better option for my case, building a prototype. But still, your app is a nice-to-have app. I think I will consider it again once I move on to building the actual site. Thx.